# How to return a file path in ZF 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a form and a controller ZF 2. I can upload a file and other data, but I can not write the @value of the path@ of the file into a database table as the value of the field. Only displays the value Array in the field of table database ! How do I change the controller or somewhere else and save the value of file path not array in field of table?
***RestaurantController.php***

```
 $form = new RestaurantForm();

        $form->get('submit')->setValue('Добавить ресторан');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $restaurants = new Restaurant();
            $form->setInputFilter($restaurants->getInputFilter());

            $data= array_merge_recursive(


                $this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray(),
                $this->getRequest()->getFiles()->toArray()
            );

            $form->setData($data);
            if ($form->isValid()){
                //array_map('unlink', glob('./public/img/restaurants*'));{
                $restaurants->exchangeArray($form->getData());
                $this->getRestaurantsTable()->saveRestaurant($restaurants);

                // Form is valid, save the form!

                // Redirect to list of albums
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin/restaurants');
            }


        }
       //else return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin');
        return array('form' => $form);
    }
```

***RestaurantForm.php***

```
           // File Input
            $file = new Element\File('restaurant_thumbnail');
            $file->setLabel('Загрузите главный рисунок ресторана')
                 ->setAttribute('id', 'image-file');
            $this->add($file);
```

***Restaurant.php***

```
                    #version2
                  //  $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

                    // File Input
                    //https://github.com/cgmartin/ZF2FileUploadExamples/blob/master/src/ZF2FileUploadExamples/Form/SingleUpload.php
                    $file = new FileInput('restaurant_thumbnail');
                    $file->setRequired(true);
                    $file->getFilterChain()->attachByName(
                        'filerenameupload',
                        array(
                            'target'          => './public/img/restaurants/*',
                            'overwrite'       => true,
                            'use_upload_name' => true,
                        )
                    );
                    $inputFilter->add($file);
```

Comment: Are you saying you want the local file path on the user's filesystem? Typically, the browser does not make that information available to the server. It only send filename, mimetype (as deduced from file extension), filesize, and the actual file contents.

Comment: Sorry i solve the problem ;) in Restaurant.php.

Comment: Were you not going to share your resolution? @V.Holovka